# Angular routes loading different component on empty path

Tags: angular

My project structure is something like this:

```
app/
--main/
  --dashboard/
    --home/
    --admin/
      --users/
```

Each folder contains a module and a component (except for auth). My idea was to have every route separated by its module, and has everithing else redirect to /dashboard.

Inside app.module I have this routes:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' }
```

Inside dashboard.module I have this:

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
    ]
}
```

Inside admin.module:

```
{ path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' }
```

And inside users.module:

```
{ path: '', component: UsersComponent }
```

Now when it runs everithing is ok, `/admin/users` loads UsersComponent, and `/dashboard` loads DashboardComponent. But when I try to go to `/`, instead of loading DashboardComponent, it loads UsersComponent. Why does this happend?

Comment: Can you share the contents of AppModule file?

Comment: Hi, is a private project, what do you exactly want to see? I don't think anything apart from the routes are necessary

Comment: The order of imports in AppModule does matter for routing. Try changing the order or share the file contents for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

How about switching the order of the children paths

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent }

    ]
}
```

Since that didn't work.  Try the order of your module imports. It seems like the blank path of the UserModule is getting chosen over the redirect to dashboard.  Make sure your RouterModule import in your app.module is last

Comment: How can I make sure that the RouterModule in the app.module is imported last?

Comment: Tough to say without seeing the app module but however the app module uses the paths, either directly in app.module with RouterModule.forRoot(paths) or imported from a separate AppRoutingModule, make sure it is the last item in your imports array